# github: how to add links to sections of readme.md

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I have a github project and want to add links to the readme
referring to sections on that readme.
I tried several ways, one typical markdown, the other html based with anchor.
Whereas everything works well in my local browser,
on github clicking at the links to not move to the proper position.

Is this maybe a bug in github??

For a concrete example

```
https://github.com/Reissner/latex-maven-plugin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen your markdown like:

```markdown
in [Section 'Features'](#ssFeatures) 

## Features <a id='ssFeatures'></a>
```

Your can try to use the following method:

```markdown
in [Section `Features`](#feature)

## Feature
```

The "[Section 'Feature']" will be a link to "#Feature"

In addition, you can follow this [README](https://github.com/Lin-jun-xiang/vscode-extensions-best/blob/main/README.md) which have a lot of "link to section".

If I have answered your question to your satisfaction, then consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Works very well now, thank you. 
One hint maybe: I used html links and so endowed the headlines with anchors `<a id='someLabel'></a>`. 
Your advise works only when this is removed from the headlines. 
Even commenting out does not help. 
That's the only piece of information missing. 

I upvoted your answer.